# JQuery do different thing based on different selector using .on() method

Tags: jquery

I have several different tasks that may need some optimization:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.one', function () {
  // do task one
});

$('.container').on('click', '.two', function () {
  // do task two
});

$('.container').on('click', '.three', function () {
  // do task three
});
```

Merged into the following:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.one, .two, .three', function () {
  // How to selectively perform each task, based on the trigger/ selector?
  // Think of if (event.type === 'mouseenter') // do sumthing
});
```

The question is how to selectively perform each different task, based on each trigger/ selector? Or is there a better way to perform this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't get why you propose `if (event.type === 'mouseenter')` if want changes the task in your above code is the element, and not the event. You only have click events.

Comment: Just an example about selective trigger, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.container').on('click', '.one, .two, .three', function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass("one")) {
    // do task one
  }
  if ($(this).hasClass("two")) {
    // do task two
  }
  if ($(this).hasClass("three")) {
    // do task three
  }
});
```

Comment: Does $(this) refer to each iteration of selector here? Thanks

Comment: `$(this)` refers to the element that was clicked.

Comment: @roasted, no, it shoudn't. The question doesn't specify that an element can have one only class!

Answer (score 8):

A better approach may just be to chain the `.on()` calls:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.one', function () {
    // do task one
}).on('click', '.two', function () {
    // do task two
}).on('click', '.three', function () {
    // do task three
});
```

Doing it this way would remove the extra processing required to check whether the element has a certain class each time the event handler is triggered.

Comment: Not to mention looks far more elegant

Comment: Like it. But the bad side is that each event not binded directly to its element has some cost. This way each time some element in container is clicked, jQuery will be asking if the element is `'.one'` or `'.two'` or `'.three'`. The only difference is that we wont see it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `hasClass` method:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.one, .two, .three', function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass('one')) {
     // 
  } else if ($this.hasClass('two')) {
     //
  } else {
    //
  }
});
```

Comment: If some element has more than one class this code will bahave different from the original.